# Regex Lookarounds, prevent ahead and behind

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a regex that I cannot get working right. I am using PCRE(php) to run it.

The regex looks for inch measurements written as fractions using the forward slash to separate the numerator and denominator. ex 1 3/8in or 19 15/16"

It would match 12 1/2" here:

```
A product description with 12 1/2" in it.
```

But I want it NOT to match if the measurement is part of a dimension, ie has an x before or after and matches this format: 19 3/4" x 19 5/8"

Example text that is matching incorrectly:

```
Product description with 19 3/4" x 19 5/8" in it.
```

This matches 5/8" when it is supposed to ignore all of it because of the x in there.

My regex currently knocks off the measure left of the x, but only ignores the whole number on the right side. The lookbehind will capture 5/8" from the example above. I need it to ignore both sides of the dimension and only match measurements that are by themselves. I am using negative look ahead and behind to match the x.

Regex:

```
/\s+(?<!x\s)\d*\s?\d+\/\d+"*\s*(in|")(?!\d*\s?x)\s*/i
```

I ran it through regex101.com's debugger and still can't figure it out. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with PCRE/php you could use (*SKIP)(*FAIL)

```
\d*\s?\d+\/\d+"*\s*(in|")\sx\s\d*\s?\d+\/\d+"*\s*(in|")(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\d*\s?\d+\/\d+"*\s*(in|")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/253)

Comment: Works for me, thanks! The verb concept is new to me too. It's always good to find another aspect of regex to put to use.